# Waitpid for a child process that execv an unexecutable script

Tags: c++, c

I am doing the following steps in my code:

- `fork()`
- `execv` in the child process to run an external script
- in the parent process:

---

```
 While( waitpid(..., WNOHANG) == 0)
 {
     //Send signal that script has started with no error
      ..
 }
```

The problem I am facing is that if the script is not executable I still end up in the above while loop and I send the signal that script has started with no errors; which is not true.

Obviously I can run a sys call and determine the permission of the script before hand, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Even if you did check the permissions that alone is no guarantee that execve will succeed. (The interpreter might not exist or be executable, the binary could be invalid, some resource constraints might be exceeded etc.). Even if you checked all that you'd have a race condition still too.

Answer (score 3):

Catching `execve` errors is tricky for exactly the reason you've found: the error is seen in the child process but you want to transfer it to the parent process. There's a nice trick to make it possible:

1. Before forking, open a `pipe` and set the close-on-exec flags (with `pipe2` and `O_CLOEXEC`, or `fcntl` if the former is not available on your system).
2. After forking, have the parent close the writing side of the pipe and read from the reading end.
3. In the child, close the reading end of the pipe, and attempt `execve`. If it fails, write `errno` to the pipe and `_exit`.
4. In the parent, if `read` returns 0, `execve` was successful. This is because a successful `execve` closes the pipe (because it's set for close-on-exec) and causes EOF on the reading end. Otherwise the value read is the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Have the child do exit(2) or some other value if it is still there after it execs the script, and test the exit value inside your parent loop. But why the loop? Just get rid of WNOHANG.